# Paragraphs become merged after processing with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My task is to highlight some words in a html file. This works fine but unfortunately in the result file the paragraphs become from some point merged together (so I have then solid text without blank lines) which looks rather ugly.

I don't really understand the reason for this, especially because this phenomenon occurs not at the beginning of the file but from some point in the middle (so the first part of the file is nice and the second part is ugly). The code is as follows:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open(file_in, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
   source = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup:
    if type(tag) is not bs4.element.Tag:
        continue
    if ll[1]<90:
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(tag).replace(ll[0], '<span    style="background-color:yellow">'+ll[0]+'</span>'))
    else:
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(tag).replace(ll[0], '<span style="background-color:red">'+ll[0]+'</span>'))
    tag.replace_with(new_soup)
with open(file_out, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

So, the file_in is completely nice, but file_out is ugly from some point in the middle, because the complete text is merged together as one clump.
Has somebody any idea how I can prevent this?

Comment: Can you add the original file?

Comment: What is the content of `ll`?

Comment: ll ist a list of tuples (a,b) where a is s word and b is number (similarity measure) but that is not really relevant. What I actually do is the following: I compare the tags of the html with words from some list. If the word is found in the tag it becomes highlighted with yellow or red depending on a similarity value which was computed before.

Comment: I don't know how to add a file. And actually I am not allowed to do it, the html file has some sensitive informations.